# Two Rails app with Devise - Sync Authentication (Helpy.io)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a standard Rails app with Devise for authentication.  I have a second app with Helpy.io installed (also Devise).  I am looking for two scenarios:

1. Authenticated Users on the Main site can access the Help site
2. Sync the user databases and once you are logged into the main you are automatically logged into the Help site and can open tickets etc.

Here is what I have tried for option 1 to start:

I have set the `SECRET_KEY_BASE` and `SESSION_STORE` on both sites the same and in session_store.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: ENV['SESSION_STORE'], domain: 'mydomain'
```

On my help site I have an application controller `before_action` that redirects to the main site if a particular session variable is nil (this is cleared on the main site if you logout).

**What Works**

If I authenticate on the main site then visit the help site everything works fine.  I can navigate the help site etc. and I am not logged in (which is fine for option 1 for now).  My users can just browse the help site and open tickets manually.  If I signout on the main site and go to the help site my re-direct kicks in and I end up back at the main app sign-in page.

**What is Broken**

If I navigate from the help site back to the main site I am automatically signed out.  I can still access the help site.  If I log back in the main site works fine again UNTIL I go back to the help site and the process starts again.

**Question**

Where do I start to look to find what in Devise or anywhere else (assuming it's Devise) that is getting cleared etc. to make my app think I am not authenticated anymore?

Comment: This sounds like a use for JWT.  I've read about them but not used them but they might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a static Jeklly site and this approach:

[Authenticate static files with Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054247/authenticate-static-files-with-devise/64491919)