# Authenticate static files with Devise?

Tags: devise

I have a static Jekyll support page on my site served in `/public/support`.  The main rails app is behind devise - the whole thing.  If you are not authenticated you get kicked back to the login.  Can I 'hide' this static site behind the Devise authentication - i.e. only allow access to the static pages when authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding this:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/

In my NGINX config I have this:

```
  location /support {
    auth_request /auth;
    auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
    error_page 403 https://$host;
  }
```

In my application controller I have:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :auth
```

This by-passes Devise.

In routes:

```
get '/auth', to: 'errors#auth'
```

It just made sense to add it to my existing custom errors controller.

Then in the controller:

```
  def auth
    user_signed_in? ? render(status: 200, layout: :blank) : render(status: 403, layout: :blank)
  end
```

The blank layout has no content - just a `<%= yield %>`.

If the user has an open Devise session they can access the support site otherwise they get redirected to the login page (default for Devise).